# Using url request with swedish letters

Tags: html, http, url, utf, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to use an API service to fetch xml data. The problem arise when I try to append a string to the url with swedish åäö in it. If I just add the swedish letters the connection fails, and when I add UTF8 encoding the reply is empty data which is wrong. This is how I do it:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://apfy.me/www.blocket.se/burken/Search?ca=11&w=3&q=segelbåt" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

When I try to open the website in browser %E5 is shown for å. I tried this all well but no success.

http://www.blocket.se/hela_sverige?q=segelb%E5t&cg=0&w=3&st=s&ca=2&is=1&l=0&md=th

Obviously I want the API service to translate å to %E5 when it fetches the html page.

Does someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the server side, the problem is solved by the apfy service